# How to map object to raw data from text search in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

When I search text with my application, it returns a hash like this which is successful, but the results are all raw hash.

```
{"queryDebugString"=>"xxx||||||", "language"=>"english", "results"=>[{"score"=>1.1, "obj"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('52b308a85a686916c9410000'), "_type"=>"Note", "occurred_on"=>2013-12-19 00:00:00 UTC, "title"=>"xxx", "type"=>"other", "description"=>"yyy zzz"}}], "stats"=>{"nscanned"=>1, "nscannedObjects"=>0, "n"=>1, "nfound"=>1, "timeMicros"=>57}, "ok"=>1.0}
```

How do I map model object on the results? Currently I am using `.new` method but `#persisted?` is false.

```
def self.search(text)
  mongo_session.command(text: collection_name.to_s, search: text.to_s, filter: all.selector)['results'].map { |row| new row['obj'] }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem simply by assigning true to @persisted of the new model.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_data = JSON.parse(text)
```

It returns a hash.

```
YourObject.new(your_data)
```

It builds your required object with all the data provided by your string

Comment: That is what I am doing. But by this mean its `#persisted?` is false, which should be true.

Comment: Could you please show what kind of request you are doing. `YourObject.where()` ?